# How split each item inside an Array String

Tags: node.js, typescript

how can i do a split for each item inside an array of strings ?

i am trying with `for`, but the typescript acuses `Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.`. I don't know another way to made that.

to contextualize , I am converting the request.files into a JSON , and JSON to Array, and i need the first numbers of the file name , which will be used as an ID to the database

my try with for:

```
let ids: Array<string> = []; //Array declaration
var myfiles = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.files)) // Convert Request Files to JSON

myfiles.map((item: any) => {
            ids.push(item.filename) //Push each file name into the array
})

for(var i = 0; i< ids.length; i++){
            ids[i] = ids[i].split('_',1) // Here would change the name of each item inside the array, but it accuses the aforementioned error
}
```

and my try with foreach, who accuses the same error

```
    ids.forEach((item, index) => {
        ids[index] = item.split('_', 1)
    })
```

**SOLUTION**

as our friend long_hair_programmer suggested, changing `ids[i] = ids[i].split('_',1)` to `ids[i] = ids[i].split('_',1)[0]` resolves the problem

Comment: can you please provide some data to work with

Comment: What's the purpose of `var myfiles = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.files))`? to clone _req.files_?

Comment: is `req.files.map(file => file.split("_"))` not what you want?

Comment: @NirajGautam the problem is the data i'm using are files uploaded from the frontend , i think i can't provide some easy way to you can replicade in your tests :/

Comment: @Sté because I wasn't able to work directly with req.files , i needed to convert it to JSON and after to array, your sugestion of ``req.files.map(file => file.split("_"))`` isn't work because typescript accuses the map as a non callable expression

Comment: `.split` returns an array even if you set the limit to 1 while each element in the `ids` array is defined as a string. You can try `ids[i] = ids[i].split('_',1)[0]` or `ids[i] = ids[i].substring(0, ids[i].indexOf('_'))`

Comment: @long_hair_programmer thank you very much , the ``ids[i] = ids[i].split('_',1)[0]`` resolve the problem